# Is there a way to check the maximum hex value allowed in a string?

Tags: regex, hex, powerapps

I have to check a string which should only contain hex values (using regex code `^[a-fA-F0-9]{1,14}$` here) for a maximum allowed value.

The allowed hex range for the string is between *0* and *1fffffffffffff*.

Is there any way to check this with regex?

Comment: doesn't the regex you posted do that already? What do you mean by `0 and 1fffffffffffff` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is that what you want:

```
^(?:[01][a-f0-9]{13}|[a-f0-9]{1,13})$
```

**Code:**

```
IsMatch(string, "^(?:[01][a-f0-9]{13}|[a-f0-9]{1,13})$", IgnoreCase)
```

Comment: Perfect, this is what I was looking for.
The leading part (?i) seems not to be supported by the regex implementation (I'm using PowerApps IsMatch() function) but the rest does exactly what it should.

Comment: @TxH: You can use the option `IgnoreCase`, see my edit

Comment: I really appreciate your ongoing support. 